# XSLT, XML: Getting the number of a step or figure for cross-references

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on XSLT to display an XML document (a section of a user manual) as HTML.  For figures, I have the following XSLT template:

```
<xsl:template match = "figure">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name = "name">
            <xsl:value-of select = "./@id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <p class = "caption">Figure <xsl:number count="figure"/>: <xsl:value-of select="./title"/></p> 
        <p class = "graphic">
            <img style="width:700px;">
                <xsl:attribute name = "src">
                    <xsl:value-of select = "./graphic/@boardno"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </img>
        </p>
    </a>
 </xsl:template>
```

This displays the figure and gives it a number based on its position in the document.  Right now, the template I have for figure references (< figref >) is this:

```
<xsl:template match = "figref">
     <a>
     <xsl:attribute name = "href">
         #<xsl:value-of select = "./@IDREF" />
     </xsl:attribute>
     <span class = "figure>
    <xsl:value-of select = "."/>   
     </span>
     </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's the XML itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="lorip.xsl"?>
    <descopim docid="LoremIpsumSample" >
        <descwp id ="descwp_LorIp">
            <titleblk>
                   <wptitle>
                    <maintlvl>Dolor Sit Amet</maintlvl>
                    <subject>Natoque Page - Description and Controls</subject>
                    <sysnomen>
                        <name>Lorem Ipsum</name>
                    </sysnomen>
                </wptitle>  
            </titleblk>
<intro>
            <title>Nunc Eget ut Vivamus</title>
            <para id="NuncEgVivpara001">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dui eu, est natoque suscipit suspendisse fringilla et. Adipisicing nonummy, urna in justo. 
                Maecenas sollicitudin nam ut a asperiores mollis. Nunc eget ut ut vivamus, sit mollis integer purus amet. Consequat 
                molestie pellentesque, ultricies tincidunt elit arcu nullam diam, in tempor morbi integer.
            </para>
        </intro>
        <sysdesc>
            <title>Nunc Eget Luctus Nullam</title>
            <desc>
                <para>
                    Neque eu maecenas pellentesque metus, gravida convallis est orci
                    <figref IDREF = "ConvEstOrcifig001" label = "Convallis est Orci">Figure </figref> sollicitudin nam ut a asperiores mollis,  
                    <figref IDREF = "AsperMollfig002" label = "Asperiores Mollis">  Figure </figref>.           
                    Amet nostra mus aptent ut commodo. Platea vestibulum vitae non felis, sed ac. Morbi quam tortor vestibulum lorem fringilla 
                    nec. Enim sed taciti dictum vehicula sit, risus at vehicula risus wisi quis, fermentum dolor ante illo quis odio at, 
                    dignissim nullam arcu nisl arcu nec ullamcorper, libero vehicula sed. <extref href = "appendixb.pdf">Appendix B (Adipisicing 
                    Nonummy)</extref> et <extref href = "appendixc.pdf">Appendix C (Maecenas sollicitudin) </extref>.
                </para>
            </desc>
        </sysdesc>
            <figsect>
                <figure id = "SuspFringfig001">
                    <title>Suspendisse Fringilla</title>
                    <graphic boardno = "SuspFringfig001.png"></graphic>
                </figure>
                <figure id = "AsperMollfig002">
                    <title>Asperiores Mollis </title>
                    <graphic boardno = "AsperMollfig002.png"></graphic>
                </figure>
                <figure id = "VivPulLitfig007">
                    <title>Viverra Pulvinar Litora</title>
                    <graphic boardno = "VivPulLitfig007.png"></graphic>
                </figure>
            </figsect>
        </descwp>
    </descopim>
```

I need a way to pull the number from the figure itself (xsl:number count="figure"), or to identify what number that figure is in the overall order, to display that with the cross-reference (e.g., "Figure 3" rather than just "Figure.")

So, the result I'm looking for, using the first figref as an example, is:

```html
<a href ="#SuspFringfig001">
  <span class = "figure">
    Figure 1  
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279694/dynamically-change-page-header-in-xslt

Comment: You really need to post a small (but complete) example of your input, and the expected output. In general, `xsl:number` numbers nodes "as you go", and there is no way to reference that elsewhere in the same transformation - so you will have to use some other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little hard to answer since you don't have a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

However, you could use a moded template to get the figure number. Just do an `xsl:apply-templates` to the `figure` that has an `id` that matches the current `IDREF` attribute.

Here's a working example of what I'm talking about...

**XML Input** (probably nothing like your actual input, but it's well-formed at least)

```
<doc>
    <figure id="fig1">
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <graphic boarno="fig1-g1"/>
    </figure>
    <figure id="fig2">
        <title>Title 2</title>        
        <graphic boarno="fig2-g1"/>
    </figure>
    <figure id="fig3">
        <title>Title 3</title>
        <graphic boarno="fig3-g1"/>
    </figure>
    <para>This should be a ref to figure 1: <figref IDREF="fig1"/></para>
    <para>This should be a ref to figure 2: <figref IDREF="fig2"/></para>
    <para>This should be a ref to figure 3: <figref IDREF="fig3"/></para>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (you didn't specify a version)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="figure">
        <a name="{@id}">
            <p class="caption">Figure <xsl:number/>: <xsl:value-of select="title"/></p> 
            <p class="graphic">
                <img style="width:700px;" src="{graphic/@boarno}"/>                
            </p>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="figure" mode="fignbr">
        <xsl:text>Figure </xsl:text>
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="figref">
        <a href="#{@IDREF}">
            <span class="figure">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//figure[@id=current()/@IDREF]" mode="fignbr"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </span>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <a name="fig1">
      <p class="caption">Figure 1: Title 1</p>
      <p class="graphic">
         <img style="width:700px;" src="fig1-g1"/>
      </p>
   </a>
   <a name="fig2">
      <p class="caption">Figure 2: Title 2</p>
      <p class="graphic">
         <img style="width:700px;" src="fig2-g1"/>
      </p>
   </a>
   <a name="fig3">
      <p class="caption">Figure 3: Title 3</p>
      <p class="graphic">
         <img style="width:700px;" src="fig3-g1"/>
      </p>
   </a>
   <para>This should be a ref to figure 1: <a href="#fig1">
         <span class="figure">Figure 1</span>
      </a>
   </para>
   <para>This should be a ref to figure 2: <a href="#fig2">
         <span class="figure">Figure 2</span>
      </a>
   </para>
   <para>This should be a ref to figure 3: <a href="#fig3">
         <span class="figure">Figure 3</span>
      </a>
   </para>
</doc>
```

You could probably also use an `xsl:key` to get the figure number more efficiently, but it's hard to give an example without better input/output/xslt samples.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, to get the number for a node using xsl:number, it has to be the context node. You can make it the context node by selecting it using xsl:apply-templates or xsl:for-each. In XSLT 2.0, xsl:number has a select attribute, so you can get the number for any node just by selecting it.

```
<xsl:template match="figref">
  <xsl:number select="idref(@ref)" count="figure"/>
</xsl:template>
```